# Report Writer - Formula based off totals

Tags: acumatica

With the Acumatica Report Writer, is it possible to use a formula in groups based off a report total?

For example, we have the need to calculate "Percent of Total Sales".

The report is grouped off Employee then Customer

The line items calculate the individual Sales (by employee/customer) of say $1000 and the total sales for that Employee is $10000.   The "Percent of Total" would be 10% in this case.

I know I can do it with a view and generate the report off that but it seems to me there was a method to calculate a "Total" formula in the report writer itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeff,

Yes you can do it using variables. Each variable or field in the report has an option that implicitly indicates when the variable is calculated - while reading the record or while printed. If your total amount is calculated while read the % can be calculated as a variable while the print operation.

Comment: Hmm..   Mike do you know if the location of the variable in the report matters, IE if the "WhileRead" formula needs to be in the same location as the "WhilePrint" ?   From our tests that before anytime we tried to use a "WhileRead" formula in an "WhilePrint" the value always came back as zero